# missing ] after element list json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to call `getPointOnMap` function on the onclick event and to give it an json object as a parameter.

here is code samples:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getResult.json",
    success: function(result) {
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var obj = result[i];
            html += "<input type='checkbox' onClick='getPointOnMap(" + obj + ")'/>" + obj.address + "<br>";
        }
        $("#myDiv").append(html);
    }
});
```

here is function `getPointOnMap`

```
function getPointOnMap(object) {
    map.addMarker({
        lat: object.lattitude,
        lng: object.longtitude,
        click: function(e) {
            alert('You clicked in this marker');
        }
    });
}
```

firebug output(also in question name):

> SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

```
getPointOnMap([object Object])
```

what should I do to pass correct object?

Comment: Be aware, this should be closed because of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813773/old-good-missing-after-element-list   You should remove your previous question.

Comment: Have you even read the comments on your exact same question @roasted has linked?

Comment: What is the `result` you are getting back? You should be able to find it in Firebug's "Net" tab

Comment: moderators marked it because they didn't understand what the question was, now I've corrected it and would be very grateful to obtain answers, but not minuses

Comment: Is it object.longtitude or object.longitude ???

Comment: @JohnSmith you can delete your own question if you want - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that. It is considered bad practice to repost the same question multiple times. It is better to re-write the question and ask for it to be re-opened - for example see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115608/re-open-closed-question

Comment: @andyb I'll able to delete it only in 2 days ;(

Comment: Yes, that's to allow time for it to be re-opened. I _think_ that any reputation lost will be returned (but possibly not instantly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is allowed to repost a question, anyway you should create your HTML Input not via string but via DOM, so you can attach the handler to the function and not on the "onclick".

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getResult.json",
    success: function(result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            (function (n) {
                var obj = result[i],
                    element = $("<input>", {type: "checkbox"});
                element.click(function () {
                    getPointMap(obj);
                });
                $(document.body).append(element, obj.address + "<br />");
            })(i)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but wouldn't all getPointMap invocations receive the last result[i] as argument with this solution? You should test your answer.

Comment: two issues: 1) shouldn't the `append` line be inside of the for-loop? 2) you have to create an additional scope, outside of `element.click(...)` and put `obj` in that scope. otherwise it will be overwritten by the following iterations in the for-loop and all click events will call `getPointMap` with the same argument. http://jsfiddle.net/FCbpm/

Comment: FYI, you can simplify `$("<input/>").attr("type", "checkbox")` to `$("<input>", {type: "checkbox"});`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, simple way:

```
html += "<input type='checkbox' onClick='getPointOnMap(" + obj.lattitude + ", " + obj.longtitude + ")'/>" + obj.address + "<br>";

function getPointOnMap(lat,lng) {
    map.addMarker({
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        click: function(e) {
            alert('You clicked in this marker');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getResult.json",
    success: function(result) {
         var myDiv = $('#myDiv');
         $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
             myDiv.append(
                 $('<INPUT>').attr('type', 'checkbox').on('click', function() {
                     getPointOnMap(obj);
                 },
                 obj.address,
                 "<br>"
             );
         });
    }
});
```